# PHP experience system // simple

Tags: php

As a begginer in php programming language i'm playing with the code, working on localhost and i did some little projects.Now i am trying to do an experience system as simple as i can, i am stuck at this part and i don't know what i am doing wrong.Some suggestions?

What i am doing wrong?

The code.

```
function update_user_xp($user_id, $xp_ammount){

    global $db;

    $params = array('user_id' => $user_id);

    $users = $db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users_xp WHERE user_id = ?", $params);

    $data = array(
        'user_xp_amount' => $xp_ammount + $users[0]['user_xp_amount'],
        'user_id' => $user_id
    );

    $db->where ('user_id', $data['user_id']);

        if ($db->update ('users_xp', $data)){

            $xpReceived = 'You have received '.$xp_ammount.' points of experience! Have a total of '.$data['user_xp_amount'].' points of experience.';

        } else {

            $xpReceived = $db->getLastError();
        }

    return $xpReceived;
}


//update_user_xp(4, 10); // user_id: 4, update with 10 points

function get_user_xp ($user_id){
    global $db;

    $params = array('user_id' => $user_id);

    $user = $db->rawQueryOne ('SELECT * FROM users_xp WHERE user_id=?', $params);

    $xp = $user['user_xp_amount'];

    return $xp;

}

function xp_need () {

    global $db;

    $xpBarNeed = $db->rawQuery("SELECT `level`, `expneeded` FROM `experience_level`");

    foreach ($xpBarNeed as $key => $value) {

        $output[] = $value;

    }


    return $output;

}


$xpn = xp_need();

$userXP = get_user_xp(4);

for($i = 0; $i < count($xpn); $i++){

            if($xpn[$i]['expneeded'] == $userXP)
            {

                //This part is working well
                print 'You are level <b>' . $xpn[$i]['level'].'</b>';


            } else {

                if ($userXP > $xpn[$i]['expneeded'] && $userXP >= $xpn[$i]['expneeded'])
            {


                        //This is the part that doesn t work, 
                        $diffEXP =  $xpn[$i]['expneeded'] -= $userXP;

                        print 'You need more exp  '. $diffEXP.'</br>';

            }
        }

}
```

This is how i am seeing in the page.
https://prnt.sc/u7z18u

Comment: Need more details on exactly what's your issue?

Comment: Doesn t calculate the difference of needed exp to the next level.

Comment: can I see the output for ``$xpn``

Comment: While you're learning, stop using `global` to give access to your database object, pass it in as a parameter instead. Defining it as a global means that all your outside code has to use `$db` as the database object, and if you use a different name, your function stops working.

Comment: Sure, here it is the output.|
https://prnt.sc/u7z5us

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to show the level based on the user's exp, right? And show how much exp needed for the next level?

Comment: Yes, that i want.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that my solution is not the best or say a well-optimized solution at the time of writing. I will try to optimize it in the near future. For the time being, you can use this:

```
<?php
    
$xpn = xp_need();
$userXP = get_user_xp(4);
    
$level = 0;
$nextExp = 0;

for ($i = count($xpn) - 1;$i >= 0;$i--)
{
    if ($userXP >= $xpn[$i]['expneeded'])
    {
        $level = $xpn[$i]['level'];
        $nextExp = $xpn[$i + 1]['expneeded'];
        break;
    }
}

$expNeeded = $nextExp - $userXP;
$percentage = round(($userXP/$nextExp) * 100);

echo "Current level: " . $level;
echo "<br/>Exp needed for the next level (" . ($level + 1) . "): " . $expNeeded;
echo "<br/>Exp achieved percentage for the next level: " . $percentage;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm.Now i need to read your code to understand where i was wrong.

Comment: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I need more reputation, but thank you very much OMi!

Comment: have a great time ahead.

Comment: I tried to do a progress bar and i am failing so much, to calculate the difference of two numbers and those are the xp needed and user exp.

`code`
   function calculatePercentage($total, $number)
{
  
 $ab = $total / $number * 100;

 return $ab;

}
`code`

Doesn t return as should, even if i round numbers, any suggestions?

Comment: I didn't understand? Percentage of what you want to calculate? Exp required fro the next level percentage?

Comment: Yes, exp percentage req for next level.

Comment: @ClaudiuCatalin I have edited my answer. Check my answer. I have added the solution to calculate the percentage.

Comment: Same as my function, starts from 50%..let's say i have 210 xp and for the next exp to level up i need 190xp  so would be around 10% in tine progress bar.

Comment: No, I had checked. It was working correctly. You might be doing somewhere else wrong then like progress bar.

Comment: function 
https://prnt.sc/u8akou

index page with progress bar
https://prnt.sc/u8al00

Comment: I did it and the same thing, your formula is good.For level 3 i need 200 and for level 4 i need 400 exp so the difference is 52% as i calculate.We have to calculate differently to make the difference of 90% instead and to show 10%.

Comment: You're so confusing!! Make clear to yourself first what exactly do you want then come back here and let me know with proper example data and expected output you need.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/u8aqf3

I just level up and i am level 4, right? For next level i need 800 and in the progress bar should be 0% not 50%, if i had 410 should be 10%.

Comment: You already have 400 exp and you need total 800 which means 400 difference so 50% is correct.

Comment: @ClaudiuCatalin I htink you're looking for this, ``$percentage = round((($userXP - $expNeeded )/$nextExp) * 100);`` update this and run your code and see if it fulfills your need

Comment: Also, you can remove ``round()`` to have a better precision percentage.

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: I think there's some logical error with my code, I will review it and let you know for any updates. For the time being, you can go with the current code.